# reshaping csv by eliminating redundant row keys and merging fields using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file in the form of:

```
'userid','metric name (1-10)','value'
```

the column 'metric name' has upwards of 10 different metrics so the same userid will have multiple rows associated with it. what I would like to accomplish would be something like this:

```
'userid1', 'metric name 1'='value1', 'metric name 2'='value2', 'metric name 3'='value3'... 'metric name 10' = 'value10'
```

A single row for each userid with all the metrics and values associated with that user in k/v pairs

I started playing around with pivot but that function doesn't really do what I need it to...

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('bps.csv')
data.pivot('entityName', 'metricName', 'value').stack()
```

I am thinking I need to iterator through the dataset by user and then grab the metrics associated with that user and build the metric k/v pairs during each iteration before going on to a new user. I did a pretty thorough job of searching the internet but I didn't find exactly what I was looking for. Please let me know if there is a simple library I could use.

Comment: Your example desired result is not valid CSV anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here come a solution using only standard python, not any framework.

Starting from the following data file :

```
id1,name,foo
id1,age,10
id2,name,bar
id2,class,example
id1,aim,demonstrate
```

You can execute the following code :

```
separator = ","
userIDKey = "userID"
defaultValue = "No data"

data = {}
#collect the data
with open("data.csv", 'r') as dataFile:
    for line in dataFile:
        #remove end of line character
        line = line.replace("\n", "")

        userID, fieldName, value = line.split(separator)

        if not userID in data.keys():
            data[userID] = {userIDKey:userID}

        data[userID][fieldName] = value

#retrieve all the columns header in use
columnsHeaders = set()
for key in data:
    dataset = data[key]
    for datasetKey in dataset :
        columnsHeaders.add(datasetKey)

columnsHeaders.remove(userIDKey)
columnsHeaders = list(columnsHeaders)
columnsHeaders.sort()

def getValue(key, dic):
    if key in dic.keys():
        return dic[key]
    else:
        return defaultValue

#then export the result
with open("output.csv", 'w') as outputFile:
    #export first line of header
    outputFile.write(userIDKey)
    for header in columnsHeaders:
        outputFile.write(", {0}".format(header))
    outputFile.write("\n")
    #and export each line
    for key in data:
        dataset = data[key]
        outputFile.write(dataset[userIDKey])
        for header in columnsHeaders:
            outputFile.write(", {0}".format(getValue(header, dataset)))
        outputFile.write("\n")
```

And then you get the following result :

```
userID, age, aim, class, name
id1, 'age'='10', 'aim'='demonstrate', 'class'='No data', 'name'='foo'
id2, 'age'='No data', 'aim'='No data', 'class'='example', 'name'='bar'
```

I think this code can be easily modified to match you objectives if required.

Hope it helps.
Arthur.